# Set Extents of MXD to new layer data source?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcpy, arcgis-desktop

Alright here I go again this forum has been good to me. I add a layer and replace its data with a shapefile I created using the following bit of python:

```
layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("C:/GIS/images.lyr")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layer)
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"images",df)[0]
lyr.replaceDataSource(projectlocation+projectname+"/Aerial/"+"/"+projectdate,"SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE","images")
lyr.name = "Images"
```

I cannot figure out how to set the extents of the mxd to the new source data I can just get it to set it to the original extents of the shp the .lyr from saved from. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out the DataFrame object in the ArcGIS help: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000003000000

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just add this line after the code you have in your question.

```
df.extent = lyr.getSelectedExtent()
```

If that does not work let me know and I will set up a test.

Comment: That just seems to set the extent to full extents (I have a grid that covers all of western canada and I am trying to set the extents of my mxd that I create to just a point layer that I add). Thank you for the pointer though.

Answer (score 2):

My first thoughts were also about lyr.getExtent() but what if you do it this way? Get the source of the layer and describe it.

```
lyrdesc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
source = lyrdesc.catalogPath
shpdesc = arcpy.Describe(source)

df.extent = shpdesc.extent
```

If neither of these work there may be an issue with the extent of the new shp you are adding.

Edit: Actually you could probably just do this and not need to do the .catalogPath stuff. Probably a slightly cleaner option but both have the same effect, though not really much difference.

```
shpdir = projectlocation + projectname + "/Aerial//" + projectdate
lyr.replaceDataSource(shpdir, "SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE", "images")
shpdesc = arcpy.Describe(shpdir + "//images.shp")
df.extent = shpdesc.extent
```

Not sure how the variables are named in the rest of your code, but the slashes might be off in mine, depending on that.